# Update values of 2 Cells at the same time

Tags: vba, excel

i have 7 worksheets containg information about a room project for my university, i need to search each sheet for a certain information, if it is a computer pool or not. 
I want to copy all pools to a extra worksheet and then can update the information from that sheet and it auto updates the orignal worksheet.

My main problem is i don't really know how a update function like that is called. i attached code in the bottom that copies all rooms to a dedicated sheet.
thanks in advance

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Start()
Dim Suche As String
Dim Blatt1 As String
Dim Blatt2 As String
Dim Blatt3 As String
Dim Blatt4 As String
Dim Blatt5 As String
Dim Blatt6 As String
Dim Blatt7 As String
Dim Result As String


Blatt1 = "1. Stock MZG"
Blatt2 = "5. Stock MZG"
Blatt3 = "6. Stock MZG"
Blatt4 = "7. Stock MZG"
Blatt5 = "8. Stock MZG"
Blatt6 = "1. Stock OEC"
Blatt7 = "2. Stock OEC"


Suche = "Poolraum"
If Len(Suche) Then
    Result = "Es wurde(n) " & AuswahlKopieren(Suche, True, Blatt1) & " Zeile(n) aus '" & Blatt1 & "' kopiert!"
    Result = Result & vbCrLf & "Es wurde(n) " & AuswahlKopieren(Suche, True, Blatt2) & " Zeile(n) aus '" & Blatt2 & "' kopiert!"
    Result = Result & vbCrLf & "Es wurde(n) " & AuswahlKopieren(Suche, True, Blatt3) & " Zeile(n) aus '" & Blatt3 & "' kopiert!"
    Result = Result & vbCrLf & "Es wurde(n) " & AuswahlKopieren(Suche, True, Blatt4) & " Zeile(n) aus '" & Blatt4 & "' kopiert!"
    Result = Result & vbCrLf & "Es wurde(n) " & AuswahlKopieren(Suche, True, Blatt5) & " Zeile(n) aus '" & Blatt5 & "' kopiert!"
    Result = Result & vbCrLf & "Es wurden(n) " & AuswahlKopieren(Suche, True, Blatt6) & " Zeile(n) aus '" & Blatt6 & "' kopiert!"
    Result = Result & vbCrLf & "Es wurde(n) " & AuswahlKopieren(Suche, True, Blatt7) & " Zeile(n) aus '" & Blatt7 & "' kopiert!"
    MsgBox (Result)
End If

End Sub

Function AuswahlKopieren(SuchStr As String, Optional Ganz As Boolean = False, Optional Arbeitsblattname As String) As Integer

Dim WSq             As Worksheet
Dim WSz             As Worksheet
Dim SuchColRng      As Range
Dim FRng            As Range
Dim CRng            As Range
Dim CRangeCustom    As Range
Dim FirstAdr        As String
Dim CArr            As Variant

Set WSq = Worksheets(Arbeitsblattname)
Set SuchColRng = WSq.Range("E:E")
Set CRangeCustom = WSq.Range("A:G")
Set WSz = Worksheets("Poolräume")

With SuchColRng
    If Ganz Then
        Set FRng = .Find(SuchStr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Else
        Set FRng = .Find(SuchStr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    End If
    If Not FRng Is Nothing Then
        FirstAdr = FRng.Address
        Do
            If CRng Is Nothing Then
                Set CRng = WSq.Rows(FRng.Row)
            Else
                Set CRng = Union(WSq.Rows(FRng.Row), CRng)
                'MsgBox ("WSq.Rows(FRng.Row): " + WSq.Rows(FRng.Row))
            End If
            Set FRng = .FindNext(FRng)
        Loop While Not FRng Is Nothing And FRng.Address <> FirstAdr
    End If
End With
If Not CRng Is Nothing Then
    Set CRng = Intersect(CRng, CRangeCustom)
    CRng.Copy
    WSz.Cells(WSz.Cells(WSz.Rows.Count, SuchColRng.Column).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    AuswahlKopieren = CRng.Cells.Count / CRng.Rows(1).Cells.Count
    MsgBox ("CRng.Cells.Count: " & CRng.Cells.Count & " CRng.Rows(1).Cells.Count: " & CRng.Rows(1).Cells.Count)
Else
    AuswahlKopieren = 0
End If
End Function

Function WSExists(ByVal WSName As String) As Boolean
Dim WS As Worksheet
For Each WS In Worksheets
    If WS.Name = WSName Then
        WSExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other way rather than copy to some other sheet you mentioned not only pool information, but also a reference where this pool was taken from (sheet, cell). After that, you can make a separate macro to put back any changes because you will know from where it was taken.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you were asking about, but you can make this code easier to work with by making `Blatt1`...`Blatt7` into an array like this:

```
Function BlattArray() as Variant
 Dim BlattStr as String
 BlattStr="1. Stock MZG,5. Stock MZG,6. Stock MZG,7. Stock MZG,8. Stock MZG,1. Stock OEC,2. Stock OEC"
 BlattArray=Split(BlattStr,",")
End Function
```

Then you can construct `Result` as:

```
Result=""
For Each Blatt in BlattArray
 Result = Result & vbCrLf & "Es wurde(n) " & AuswahlKopieren(Suche, True, Cstr(Blatt)) & " Zeile(n) aus '" & Blatt & "' kopiert!"
Next
```

That way, whenever you add another sheet, you just add its name to the `BlattStr` string.